# Update Query in MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Would like to seek help in finding what is wrong with these codes. Before I added op_plan, op_reg, op_proj, audit_plan, audit_reg, audit_proj, it was perfectly working fine. But upon adding, db and table does not update. I tried looking for answers from this site, still no luck. Thanks in advance!

The error message is:
Notice: Undefined index: op_plan in updateplan
Notice: Undefined index: op_reg in updateplan
Notice: Undefined index: op_proj in updateplan
Notice: Undefined index: audit_plan in updateplan
Notice: Undefined index: audit_reg in updateplan
Notice: Undefined index: audit_proj in updateplan
updateplan
Your changes have been saved!

```
<?php
include ('db_config.php');

$alp_plan = $_POST['alp_plan'];
$alveo_plan = $_POST['alveo_plan'];
$avida_plan = $_POST['avida_plan'];
$amaia_plan = $_POST['amaia_plan'];
$bellavita_plan = $_POST['bellavita_plan'];
$vismin_plan = $_POST['vismin_plan'];
$finance_plan = $_POST['finance_plan'];
$finance_reg = $_POST['finance_reg'];
$finance_proj = $_POST['finance_proj'];
$hr_plan = $_POST['hr_plan'];
$hr_reg = $_POST['hr_reg'];
$hr_proj = $_POST['hr_proj'];
$bpaqa_plan = $_POST['bpaqa_plan'];
$bpaqa_reg = $_POST['bpaqa_reg'];
$bpaqa_proj = $_POST['bpaqa_proj'];
$isu_plan = $_POST['isu_plan'];
$isu_reg = $_POST['isu_reg'];
$isu_proj = $_POST['isu_proj'];
$bench_plan = $_POST['bench_plan'];
$bench_reg = $_POST['bench_reg'];
$bench_proj = $_POST['bench_proj'];
$admin_plan = $_POST['admin_plan'];
$admin_reg = $_POST['admin_reg'];
$admin_proj = $_POST['admin_proj'];
$inbound_plan = $_POST['inbound_plan'];
$inbound_reg = $_POST['inbound_reg'];
$inbound_proj = $_POST['inbound_proj'];
$records_plan = $_POST['records_plan'];
$records_reg = $_POST['records_reg'];
$records_proj = $_POST['records_proj'];
$alp_reg = $_POST['alp_reg'];
$alp_proj = $_POST['alp_proj'];
$alveo_reg = $_POST['alveo_reg'];
$alveo_proj = $_POST['alveo_proj'];
$avida_reg = $_POST['avida_reg'];
$avida_proj = $_POST['avida_proj'];
$amaia_reg = $_POST['amaia_reg'];
$amaia_proj = $_POST['amaia_proj'];
$bellavita_reg = $_POST['bellavita_reg'];
$bellavita_proj = $_POST['bellavita_proj'];
$vismin_reg = $_POST['vismin_reg'];
$vismin_proj = $_POST['vismin_proj'];
$op_plan = $_POST['op_plan'];
$op_reg = $_POST['op_reg'];
$op_proj = $_POST['op_proj'];
$audit_plan = $_POST['audit_plan'];
$audit_reg = $_POST['audit_reg'];
$audit_proj = $_POST['audit_proj'];
$remarks = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['remarks']);
$year = $_POST['year'];





$sql = "UPDATE manpowerplan SET alp_plan = '$alp_plan', alveo_plan = '$alveo_plan', avida_plan = '$avida_plan', amaia_plan = '$amaia_plan', bellavita_plan = '$bellavita_plan', vismin_plan = '$vismin_plan', finance_plan = '$finance_plan', finance_reg = '$finance_reg', finance_proj = '$finance_proj', hr_plan = '$hr_plan', hr_reg = '$hr_reg', hr_proj = '$hr_proj', bpaqa_plan = '$bpaqa_plan', bpaqa_reg = '$bpaqa_reg', bpaqa_proj = '$bpaqa_proj', isu_plan = '$isu_plan', isu_reg = '$isu_reg', isu_proj = '$isu_proj', bench_plan = '$bench_plan', bench_reg = '$bench_reg', bench_proj = '$bench_proj', admin_plan = '$admin_plan', admin_reg = '$admin_reg', admin_proj = '$admin_proj', inbound_plan = '$inbound_plan', inbound_reg = '$inbound_reg', inbound_proj = '$inbound_proj', records_plan = '$records_plan', records_reg = '$records_reg', records_proj = '$records_proj', alp_reg = '$alp_reg', alp_proj = '$alp_proj', alveo_reg = '$alveo_reg', alveo_proj = '$alveo_proj', avida_reg = '$avida_reg', avida_proj = '$avida_proj', amaia_reg = '$amaia_reg', amaia_proj = '$amaia_proj', bellavita_reg = '$bellavita_reg', bellavita_proj = '$bellavita_proj', vismin_reg = '$vismin_reg', vismin_proj = '$vismin_proj', op_plan = '$op_plan', op_reg = '$op_reg', op_proj = '$op_proj', audit_plan = '$audit_plan', audit_reg = '$audit_reg', audit_proj = '$audit_proj', remarks = '$remarks' WHERE year = '$year'";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql); 
    if(!$query)
        echo $sql;
    else
        echo "Your changes have been saved! " ;
?>
```

Comment: What does happen? Have you switched on PHP error messages?

Comment: if(!$query) echo mysqli_error();

Comment: Echo the $sql and then copy paste the query into DB editor and check the error.

Comment: `if(!$query)
        echo mysqli_error($con);`

Comment: Note: Part of the beauty of the mysqli API is that it affords the use of prepared statements. So, once you have a working query, rewrite it take advantage of this additional security.

Comment: maybe there is a single quote in one of the params?

Answer (score 0):

Those variable `op_plan, op_reg, op_proj, audit_plan, audit_reg, audit_proj,`
are undefined, you should add them to form to, after you add them to table and SQL query, now they $_POST doesn't get them and make them as 'undefined'.

please add the form Code so can how look.